# [rails]: implementing multiple indices on a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm designing a music database (SQLite v3) in Rails 6.1.1 with the following specifications:

- Each song can belong exclusively to one album, which in turn exclusively belongs to an artist.
- Each song can belong to multiple playlists, while each playlist can have multiple songs.

What is the best way I can keep track of a song's position in a corresponding album or playlist? For instance, I should be able to know that "this song is the 2nd song of the X album, the 27th song of the Y playlist, and the 13th song of the Z playlist".

The two-fold method I've conceived of in my head is as follows:

- Maintain an `album_index` column in the Songs table. This is easy to implement since one song only belongs to a single album.
- Maintain multiple `playlist_{PLAYLIST_ID}_index` columns in the Songs table. This seems to be difficult. The only implementation method I can think of is to use active record callbacks every time Playlist records are created or deleted.

Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: Use an intermediate model / table with `playlist_id`, `song_id`, and `index`. Maybe `PlaylistItem`. Connect songs and playlists via [`has_many :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: @Stefan I would avoid calling a column `index` as thats a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just a run of the mill many-to-many relationship. You need a separate join table that links the rows in `songs` and `playlists`. And since you want to actually store additional data (the position) you want a model.

You can generate the model with:

```
rails g model PlaylistItem song:belongs_to playlist:belongs_to position:integer
```

Feel free to name it whatever you feel like.

You can then link songs and playlists with an indirect association:

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :playlist_items
  has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_items
end

# columns:
# - song_id [Bigint] foreign key
# - playlist_id [Bigint] foreign key
# - position [Int]
class PlaylistItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :playlist
end

class Playlist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :playlist_items
  has_many :songs, through: :playlist_items
end
```

Comment: I made a slight mistake. It should be `position:integer` and not `position:int`.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you're running into with the playlist table is the Many-Many relationship between the song and playlist table. To resolve this issue you can create an intermediate table that would contain at most three columns, the song id, the playlist id, and finally the position. The key would then be the composite of the song and playlist id ensuring uniqueness and include the position of the song in each playlist.

Comment: Thank you very much!